# Image rotation around its center in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding

I have a program which can draw images to a map, but i want to rotate them with x degree.

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="map" Margin="0" MapServiceToken="TOKEN" MapTapped="OnMapTapped">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locomotives}" x:Name="mic">
                <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding MarkerImage}" Height="20"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.62745"
                               Tag="{Binding Index}"
                               Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" 
                               Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding Anchor}" Tapped="Image_Tapped">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform  Angle="{Binding Angle}"></RotateTransform>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl>
        </Maps:MapControl>
```

And i want to rotate the image around its NormalizedAnchorPoint (nearly its center) but if i move the map, images rotate around the (0.5, 0.62745) point of the MapControl.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: So are you trying make a little like radar effect around each marker or something? Are you saying your normalizedanchorpoint is adopting your rendertransformorigin?